# Is there a faster version of numpy.random.shuffle?

Tags: python, numpy, shuffle

I'm using `numpy.random.shuffle` in order to compute a statistic on randomized columns of a 2D array. The Python code is as follows:

```python
import numpy as np

def timeline_sample(series, num):
    random = series.copy()
    for i in range(num):
        np.random.shuffle(random.T)
        yield random
```

The speed I get is something like this:

```python
import numpy as np
arr = np.random.sample((50, 5000))
```

```python
%%timeit
for series in timeline_sample(rnd, 100):
    np.sum(series)
```

```
1 loops, best of 3: 391 ms per loop
```

I tried to Cythonize this function but I wasn't sure how to replace the call to `np.random.shuffle` and the function was 3x slower. Does anyone know how to accelerate or replace this? It is currently the bottleneck in my program.

Cython code:

```python
cimport cython

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np


@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)
def timeline_sample2(double[:, ::1] series, int num):
    cdef double[:, ::1] random = series.copy()
    cdef int i
    for i in range(num):
        np.random.shuffle(random.T)
        yield random
```

Comment: My ballpark calculations result in a throughput of about 600 MB/s, which is not too shabby given that you do multiple passes through the data *and* generate about 3M random integers per `timeline_sample` call. OTOH your data set is 70 KiB which should fit into L2 cache, where memory bandwidth should be significantly larger still. I'm not sure whether performance can be increased significantly.

Comment: Thank you for your ballpark numbers. My real code will rather be an array of dimensions 40 x 5000, will that significantly affect your estimations?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's likely that this will give a nice speed boost:

```
from timeit import Timer

import numpy as np
arr = np.random.sample((50, 5000))

def timeline_sample(series, num):
    random = series.copy()
    for i in range(num):
        np.random.shuffle(random.T)
        yield random

def timeline_sample_fast(series, num):
    random = series.T.copy()
    for i in range(num):
        np.random.shuffle(random)
        yield random.T

def timeline_sample_faster(series, num):
    length = arr.shape[1]
    for i in range(num):
        yield series[:, np.random.permutation(length)]

def consume(iterable):
    for s in iterable:
        np.sum(s)

min(Timer(lambda: consume(timeline_sample(arr, 1))).repeat(10, 10))
min(Timer(lambda: consume(timeline_sample_fast(arr, 1))).repeat(10, 10))
min(Timer(lambda: consume(timeline_sample_faster(arr, 1))).repeat(10, 10))
#>>> 0.2585161680035526
#>>> 0.2416607110062614
#>>> 0.04835709399776533
```

Forcing it to be contiguous does increase the time, but not by a ton:

```
def consume(iterable):
    for s in iterable:
        np.sum(np.ascontiguousarray(s))

min(Timer(lambda: consume(timeline_sample(arr, 1))).repeat(10, 10))
min(Timer(lambda: consume(timeline_sample_fast(arr, 1))).repeat(10, 10))
min(Timer(lambda: consume(timeline_sample_faster(arr, 1))).repeat(10, 10))
#>>> 0.2632228760048747
#>>> 0.25778737501241267
#>>> 0.07451769898761995
```

Comment: I could have sworn that I tried this (maybe I was permuting the rows then). This is indeed faster, thank you!

Comment: What makes this faster? `np.random.permutation` just calls `shuffle` internally

Comment: @endolith `permutation` is only shuffling a few numbers; shuffling the original array requires moving much more data back and forth, and the implementation of that actually requires three copies for every row. In contrast, indexing is already well optimized and only requires one copy per row.

Comment: Does that mean that `timeline_sample_faster` is returning a shuffled view of the array rather than shuffling it in-place?

Comment: @endolith I don't believe so, I think indexing produces a copy.

Comment: @Veedrac I needed to adjust 6 character for that, so I let you :p, bummer is that the timeline_sample_faster is not faster with a small vector :(

Answer (score 1):

Randomizing rows will be cheaper, the code below is equivalent in functionality but is 
about 3 times faster on my machine.

```
def timeline_sample_fast(series, num):
   random = series.T.copy()
   for i in range(num):
       np.random.shuffle(random)
       yield random.T



arr = np.random.sample((600, 50))

%%timeit                         
for s in timeline_sample(arr, 100):
    np.sum(s)

10 loops, best of 3: 55.5 ms per loop

%%timeit
for s in timeline_sample_fast(arr, 100):
   np.sum(s)

10 loops, best of 3: 18.6 ms per loop
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Unfortunately, with array dimensions closer to my real code this is no longer true. It is still faster but not by much. I edited my question to include those dimensions. I should have done so from the start. I apologize.

Comment: I also need the rows to be C-contiguous for the C code that uses the randomized array. So if I have to copy the values returned by 'timeline_sample_fast` into a C-contiguous array of equal shape, I guess, the small speed advantage is lost.